# How can I download a single merged JSON file within a loop whilst using Google API and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, google-places, stringify

I have a script that is looping through an array of Google Place IDs and returns some of their Place Details. I’m then using `JSON.Stringify` to output the data in JSON format.

```
function initMap() {

 //====Array of Google Place IDs=====//
  
var placeid_list = [{
    "placeid": 'ChIJryijc9s0K4gRG9aU7SDTXdA',
  }, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJaZ6Hg4iAhYARxTsHnDFJ9zE',
  }, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJl64IQXrYzUwR8CVOTRf_h3o',
  }, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJBTMkuph-zkwR9oEF8Nv3Z0o',
  }, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJ4QbSBj8IzkwRGi0ILu03_VA',
  }, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJc2nSALkEdkgRkuoJJBfzkUI',
  }, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJmzrzi9Y0K4gRgXUc3sTY7RU',
  }];

  function setPlaces() {

    var json = placeid_list;

     //====Loop for Place IDs=====//

    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
      var data = json[i];
      createPlace(data);
    }
  }
  function createPlace(data) {
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("placeResults"));
    console.log(data);
    service.getDetails({
      placeId: data.placeid,
      fields: [
        "name",
        "formatted_address",
        "place_id",
        "geometry",
        "type",
        "formatted_phone_number",
        "rating",
        "reviews",
        "website",
        "url",
        "photos",
        "opening_hours",
        "price_level"],

    }, function (result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      placeResults(data, result);

    });
  }
  function placeResults(data, result) {

 //====Merge Data from each of looped Place IDs=====//

    const mergedObj = Object.assign(result);
    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(mergedObj, 0, 2);
    const jsonFile = document.getElementById("placeResults").textContent += jsonStr;

    //====Output JSON data in JSON File=====//

    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([jsonFile], {
    type: "application/json"
    }));
    a.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);

    //====Output JSON data in text format=====//

    //document.getElementById("placeResults").textContent += jsonStr;

  }
  setPlaces();
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

I’m trying to make it so that the combined JSON details for each place can be downloaded as a single file. Currently, the code above is generating 7 separate file downloads (the same amount of place IDs I have). Each of these files contains data for all of the Place IDs. But I only need 1 of these files.

I have been able to combine the data from each of the 7 place IDs and display it using the following:

```
const mergedObj = Object.assign(result);
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(mergedObj, 0, 2);
const jsonFile = document.getElementById("placeResults").textContent += jsonStr;

//====Output JSON data in text format=====//
    
//document.getElementById("placeResults").textContent += jsonStr;
```

To generate a downloadable JSON file containing the place details, I'm using this:

```
const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([jsonFile], {
    type: "application/json"
    }));
    a.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
```

I'm hoping someone can help me in getting just 1 file to download when the script runs. Ideally, the process if to loop through all the place IDs, output their data in JSON format, merge it all, then download a single file containing everything.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asynchronous calls to the Google `PlacesService()`, where the responses come back in an unpredictable order and timing. In order to collect the responses you could either use promises, or a counter that keeps track of the calls and returns.

Here is your code modified using a counter. The code is untested since I don't have all the details.

Some notes:

- the `createPlace()` function has a callback, which is called on success and failure
- a count variable gets incremented before calling `createPlace()`, and decremented in the callback function
- the callback function adds the result to the resultArray variable
- all calls are done once the counter reaches 0 in the callback function, at which point to call `placeResults()`

```
function initMap() {

 //====Array of Google Place IDs=====//
  var placeid_list = [
    { "placeid": 'ChIJryijc9s0K4gRG9aU7SDTXdA' },
    { "placeid": 'ChIJaZ6Hg4iAhYARxTsHnDFJ9zE' },
    { "placeid": 'ChIJl64IQXrYzUwR8CVOTRf_h3o' },
    { "placeid": 'ChIJBTMkuph-zkwR9oEF8Nv3Z0o' },
    { "placeid": 'ChIJ4QbSBj8IzkwRGi0ILu03_VA' },
    { "placeid": 'ChIJc2nSALkEdkgRkuoJJBfzkUI' },
    { "placeid": 'ChIJmzrzi9Y0K4gRgXUc3sTY7RU',}
  ];

  function setPlaces() {
    let resultArray = [];
    let callCount = 0;
    placeid_list.forEach(data => {
      callCount++;
      createPlace(data, function(result) {
        callCount--;
        if(result) {
          resultArray.push(result);
        }
        if(!callCount) {
          // all async calls done
          placeResults(resultArray);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function createPlace(data, callback) {
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("placeResults"));
    console.log(data);
    service.getDetails({
      placeId: data.placeid,
      fields: [ "name", "formatted_address", "place_id", "geometry", "type", "formatted_phone_number", "rating", "reviews", "website", "url", "photos", "opening_hours", "price_level" ],
    }, function (result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        callback();
        return;
      }
      callback(result);
    });
  }

  function placeResults(resultArray) {
    const mergedObj = Object.assign(resultArray);
    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(mergedObj, 0, 2);
    const jsonFile = document.getElementById("placeResults").textContent += jsonStr;

    //====Output JSON data in JSON File=====//
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([jsonFile], {
      type: "application/json"
    }));
    a.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }

  setPlaces();
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer Peter. This code worked and I now how the JSON file to work with. I'll upvote this and mark as correct answer